# How to properly debug Completables in rxjava2, and why no one talks about chaining them?

Tags: android, rx-java2, rx-android, android-room

I'm having a serious problem with Room and RxJava2.
I can't execute some operations on the Room database with some Rx code
The actual problem occurs in the concatenation of the observables

```
public void agregarCompraProductoYActualizarProductos(){ //THE PROBLEM IS ONLY HERE
    Completable c = insertarClienteDummy().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
    Completable c2 = insertarCompra().subscribeOn(Schedulers.trampoline());
    Completable c3 = actualizarProductos().subscribeOn(Schedulers.trampoline());

    c.andThen(c2)
            .andThen(c3)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(() -> irAFacturaActivity());

//        Completable.concatArray(c, c2, c3) | This shows the same output
//                .subscribe(() -> irAFacturaActivity());

}

private Completable insertarClienteDummy(){
    Cliente cliente = new Cliente(111, "Juan");
    Repositorio repo = new RepositorioCliente(getApplicationContext());
    return repo.agregarElemento(cliente);
}

private Completable insertarCompra(){

    String fecha = (String) DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a", Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

    Repositorio repo = new RepositorioCompra(getApplicationContext());
    Completable p = repo.agregarElemento(new Compra(0, 111, fecha))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.trampoline());

    RepositorioCompra repo2 = new RepositorioCompra(getApplicationContext());
    Completable c = repo2
            .darCompraPorFecha(fecha)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .map(compra -> crearCompraProductosPorCodigoCompra(compra.getCodigo()))
            .flatMapCompletable(compraProductos -> agregarCompraProductos(compraProductos))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.trampoline());
    return p.andThen(c);

}

private ArrayList crearCompraProductosPorCodigoCompra(int codigoCompra){
    ArrayList<CompraProducto> compraProductos = null;
    compraProductos = new ArrayList<CompraProducto>();
    for (Producto p: productos) {
        compraProductos.add(new CompraProducto(0, codigoCompra, p.getCodigo(), p.getCantidad()));
    }
    return compraProductos;
}

private Completable agregarCompraProductos(ArrayList<CompraProducto> compraProductos){
    RepositorioCompraProducto repo = new RepositorioCompraProducto(getApplicationContext());
    return repo.agregarCompraProductos(compraProductos.toArray(new CompraProducto[compraProductos.size()]));
}

private Completable actualizarProductos(){
    RepositorioProducto repo2 = new RepositorioProducto(getApplicationContext());
    return repo2.actualizarProductos(productos.toArray(new Producto[productos.size()]));
}

public void irAFacturaActivity(){
    Intent i = new Intent(this, FacturaActivity.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putSerializable(PRODUCTOS, productos);
    i.putExtras(bundle);
    limpiarCache();
    startActivity(i);
}
```

The actual output of this code is:

Actual

> I/RespositorioCompra: darCompraPorFecha main
>
> I/RespositorioCliente: Agregar elementoRxCachedThreadScheduler-1
>
> I/RespositorioCompra: Agregar elemento RxCachedThreadScheduler-1
>
> I/RespoCompraProducto: AgregarCompraProductos pool-1-thread-1

But this is the desired output

> I/RespositorioCliente: Agregar elementoRxCachedThreadScheduler-1
>
> I/RespositorioCompra: Agregar elemento RxCachedThreadScheduler-1
>
> I/RespositorioCompra: darCompraPorFecha RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 //Actually is in main
>
> I/RespoCompraProducto: AgregarCompraProductos RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 //Actually is in pool-1-thread-1
>
> I/RespositorioProducto: ActualizarProductos RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 //this is not actually even happening

Comment: When you have multiple `subscribeOn()` invocations on the same observer chain, only the first one has an effect. Also, using the `trampoline()` scheduler probably doesn't do what you want. Try using a `TestScheduler` instead.

Comment: I appreciate your attention but removing trampoline() won't solve  the problem, also how can i apply TestScheduler?

Comment: You need to clean up the use of `subscribeOn()` before anything else

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this uncontrollable problem was to create an inner method in the proper DAO class with the `@Transaction` and execute there all the methods related to the database.